# Product names are N/A and remain the same after renaming in Prestashop [1.7.8.2]

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am a junior (barely) dev and recently inherited a Prestashop project (version 1.7.8.2).
In both admin panel and main page all the products have N/A instead of actual name.
Even if I rename them they remain N/A.
**ALTHOUGH In Database all the names are displayed correctly.**
The site is in French only so in ps_lang table there is only one lang mentioned (Thus it's not possible to add translation to it).  [image: Product tab in admin panel]
[image: DB Screenshot]

I tried exporting products in CVS then deleted them from admin panel and then importing them again, didn't work.

Did anyone come across this issue? What are possible reasons of this bug?

Answer (score 0):

IDs in tables ps_product and ps_product lang don't match.
Probable solution - try rewrite IDs in ps_product table manually, might take time, might not work, but at least I can see clearly the problem here.